# Search for questions based on badges and tags

Tags: support, tags, badges, search

How do I search for questions with a certain tag and that have been awarded a badge? I.e. search for all questions tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and have earned the badge [Favorite Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question)

I have found out how to search by either one separately: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [Favorite Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question).

So is this even possible, or can you currently only see them separately?

Answer (score 3):

Badges aren't indexed for searching in that manner at all, so at the moment this is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the 'badges' table in the Data Explorer does not contain post information ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236582/add-post-id-to-badges-table-when-applicable) is an old, popular feature request to enable this).

For this particular badge, you can check it with the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/514243/650507/) on the 'votes' table, where marks-as-favorite are stored:

```sql
SELECT p.id AS [Post Link], COUNT(*) AS Favorites
  FROM votes AS v
  INNER JOIN posts AS p ON v.postid = p.id
  INNER JOIN posttags AS pt ON p.id = pt.postid
  INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = pt.tagid
  WHERE v.votetypeid = 5 -- Marked as favorite
    AND t.tagname = lower(##TagName:string##)
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= ##NumberOfFavorites:int## 
  ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

The first results (for parameters 'c++', 25) are the following questions:

[Compiling Qt 4.8.x for Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113400)

[Decent profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170036)

[What are the advantages of using the C++ Boost libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125580)

Note that SEDE data is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning.

#### EDIT:

As @rene points out, the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/514243/650506/) will probably be faster, as it saves a join:

```sql
SELECT p.id AS [Post Link], p.favoritecount
  FROM posts AS p
  INNER JOIN posttags AS pt ON p.id = pt.postid
  INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = pt.tagid
  WHERE t.tagname = lower(##TagName:string##)
    AND p.favoritecount >= ##NumberOfFavorites:int## 
  ORDER BY p.favoritecount
```

Comment: You beat me to it by mere seconds .... for this particular case the posts table holds a denormalized field: `favoritecount` which will spare you all those joins but for other badges to get them linked to a post your approach is the way to go.